# d3.js adding polygon inside rectangle

Tags: d3.js

How to add polygon inside rectangle?, below is the code i have but it is not showing polygon inside rectangle. could you please help me.

```
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")

var rectangle = svgContainer.append("rect")
                              .style("stroke", "black")
                              .style("fill", "none")
                             .attr("x", 50)
                            .attr("y", 50)
                           .attr("width", 100)
                          .attr("height", 100);


var cir =   rectangle.append("polygon")       // attach a polygon
    .style("stroke", "black")  // colour the line
    .style("fill", "none")     // remove any fill colour
    .attr("points", "30,50,100,150,100,150");  // x,y points
```

Answer (score 1):

You are making the polygon with in the rect DOM which is incorrect
You should be attaching the polygon to the svg
So it should be

```
svgContainer.append("polygon")
```

corrected code below:

```
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")

var rectangle = svgContainer.append("rect")
                              .style("stroke", "black")
                              .style("fill", "none")
                             .attr("x", 50)
                            .attr("y", 50)
                           .attr("width", 100)
                          .attr("height", 100);


var cir =   svgContainer.append("polygon")       // attach a polygon to the svg
    .style("stroke", "black")  // colour the line
    .style("fill", "none")     // remove any fill colour
    .attr("points", "30,50,100,150,100,150");  // x,y points
```

Working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/pgerw8va/)

To make the polygon appear within the rectangle you will need to provide the polygon points/coordinates accordingly.
Just by making the polygon within the rect DOM element will not make it show withing the rectangle.
Hope this clears your concern.

Comment: Thanks for the details - Cyril.  is there way i can fit triangle exactly center of rectangle.

Comment: @gorants you can center any triangle by calculating the center and providing the points in the array check my demo here http://jsfiddle.net/pgerw8va/2/
Now you will have to write an algorithm to calculate the centroid of a figure.

Comment: Thanks Cyril .. Appreciated your help